# Only Allowing 1 Upvote Via MYSQL Explode

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating an upvote system on my site.  Currently, the upvotes are working but I want to limit the upvotes to 1 per user.
The votes are added by updating the total votes:

```
mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE news SET votes=(votes + 1) WHERE ID='". $_POST['id1'] . "'");
```

And then I record that the user voted on that article by using:

```
mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE users SET votes=CONCAT(votes,'" . $_POST['id1'] .",') WHERE ID='". $_SESSION['ID'] . "'");
```

Now, I try to implement only allowing an upvote if the article id is not already in their "votes" database.  I'm storing votes like `1,4,7,12` so that user voted on articles 1, 4, 7 and 12.  So I'm trying to use explode to check if they already voted on an article:

```
$results = mysqli_query($link2,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID ='" . $_SESSION['ID'] . "'");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array( $results )){

  $votes = explode(",", $result['votes']);

  foreach($votes as $vote) {

  if ($vote = $_POST['id1']) {
//Do nothing
} else {
mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE news SET votes=(votes + 1) WHERE ID='".     $_POST['id1'] . "'");
mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE users SET votes=CONCAT(votes,'" . $_POST['id1'] .",') WHERE ID='". $_SESSION['ID'] . "'");
```

Any help or suggestions on a better way to accomplish the same thing would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It might be easier to create a new record for each vote and have the query do the work.

Comment: Comma-separated lists in databases are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: For more about why you want to use a vote table and not comma-separated fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up on not using a list, working on a vote table now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a vote table:

```
CREATE TABLE voted (
   user_id INT NOT NULL,
   news_id INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (news_id) REFERENCES news(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4;
```

Add a unique constraint on this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_voted_nn_1 ON voted (user_id,news_id);
```

Then use some php code which exits on a constraint issue:

```
$connection = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$query="INSERT INTO voted (user_id,news_id) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt=$connection->query($query);
$stmt->bind("ii",$_SESSION['ID'],$_POST['ID']);
$stmt->execute();
$error=$mysqli_stmt->errno($stmt);
if(!$error) update your news vote;
else do nothing or say something to user;
```

Comment: Sweet, I'm trying this out now.  Should I replace the VALUES (?,?) with my variables, or does the (?,?) link with the "ii"?  I'm not too familiar wtih PDO

Comment: Please read up on mysqli/pdo then because your version was slightly hackable. This version is not. PS: FOund one more small issue in your code: **if ($vote = $_POST['id1'])** should be **if ($vote== $_POST['id1'])**

Comment: Hmm. I've got the table set up but it won't insert anything into the table.  My current code is: https://gist.github.com/alteredorange/0fad2c9a67c3a1c0d185

Comment: Got it working with some mysqli, thanks for the help!